# How to refresh component after MatDialog close and data updated in database in Angular 6?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, angular6

I am learning a MEAN stack app with angular 6. Here I want to refresh the component after adding a new client/car/driver/booking or updating a new client/car/driver/booking. But after adding a new value, the component showing all the values doesn't update or refresh(not able to see the current value at that time), but when i route between component and then go back to the same component it updates and shows all the values.

I want that as the value is added or updated from a dialog form, it gets displayed at that time.

Here is `add client component`

```js
export class AddClientComponent implements OnInit {

  clientForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder,
    private clientService: ClientService,
    private toastr: ToastrService,
    private router: Router,
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef < AddClientComponent > ) {

    this.clientForm = this.fb.group({
      'clientname': new FormControl(""),
      'clientphoneno': new FormControl(""),
      'clientemail': new FormControl(""),
      'clientaddress': new FormControl("")
    });

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.router.navigate(['/admin/clients']);
  }

  saveClient(formdata: any) {
    let theForm = this.clientForm.value;
    this.clientService.addClient(theForm).subscribe(data => {
      if (data.success === false) {
        this.toastr.error(data.message);
      } else {
        this.toastr.success(data.message);
        this.ngOnInit();
        this.dialogRef.close();
      }
      this.clientForm.reset();
    });
  }

  close() {
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }

}
```

here is the `client component` where the added values are displayed

```js
export class ClientsComponent implements OnInit {

  public currentClient: IClient;
  clients: any;

  addClientDialogRef: MatDialogRef < AddClientComponent > ;
  editClientDialogRef: MatDialogRef < EditClientComponent > ;

  constructor(public dialog: MatDialog,
    private dialogService: DialogService,
    private clientService: ClientService,
    private router: Router) {}

  openAddClientDialog() {
    this.dialogService.open(AddClientComponent, {
      width: '500px'
    })
  }

  openEditClientDialog(id) {
    this.dialogService.open(EditClientComponent, {
      width: '500px',
      data: {
        'id': id
      }
    })
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getAllClients();
  }

  getAllClients() {
    this.clientService.getClients().subscribe((res) => {
      this.clients = res;
    }, err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  }

  deleteClient(id) {
    this.clientService.deleteClient(id)
      .subscribe(res => {
        this.router.navigate(['./clients']);
        this.ngOnInit();
      }, (err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }


}
```

here is the `client service`

```js
addClient(oClient) {
  let headers = new Headers({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  });
  let options = new RequestOptions({
    headers: headers
  });
  return this._http.post('http://localhost:3000/admin/clients/add', JSON.stringify(oClient), options).pipe(
    map((response: Response) => response.json()));
}

getClients() {
  let headers = new Headers({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  });
  let options = new RequestOptions({
    headers: headers
  });
  return this._http.get('http://localhost:3000/admin/clients', options).pipe(
    map((response: Response) => response.json()));
}

getClient(clientid) {
  let headers = new Headers();
  headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  let options = new RequestOptions({
    headers: headers
  });
  return this._http.get(`http://localhost:3000/admin/clients/${clientid}`, options).pipe(
    map((response: Response) => response.json()));
}

editClient(clientId, oClient) {
  let headers = new Headers({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  });
  let options = new RequestOptions({
    headers: headers
  });
  return this._http.put(`http://localhost:3000/admin/clients/edit/${clientId}`, JSON.stringify(oClient), options).pipe(
    map((response: Response) => response.json()));
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're only calling `getAllClients()` during the `OnInit` lifecycle hook of `ClientsComponent`. This means it will **only** load the clients on initialisation of the component (which is why you see the new client when you navigate away and back again, as the component re-initialises and the `OnInit` lifecycle hook is fired again).

To counter that, you have two options (well, more than two if you were using state management (ngRx for example)).

1) When you've added your new client, and closed the dialog, immediately call `getAllClients()` again, by subscribing to the `afterClosed` event of `MatDialog`

```
this.addClientDialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(() => { this.getAllClients(); } );
```

or

2) Provide the new client object via the `afterClosed` event from the dialog itself, and push the new object to you `clients` array. The only caveat being, you'll need to return the new client object from your HTTP request in `saveClient`

**AddClientComponent**

```
saveClient(formdata: any) {
    let theForm = this.clientForm.value;
    this.clientService.addClient(theForm).subscribe(data => {
       if (data.success === false) {
          this.toastr.error(data.message);
       } else {
          this.toastr.success(data.message);
          this.ngOnInit();
          this.dialogRef.close(data.client); // <--- Assuming the new object comes under the 'client' key of your response.
       }
       this.clientForm.reset();
    });
}
```

**ClientsComponent**

```
addClientDialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe((client: Client) => {
    this.clients.push(client);
}
```

The `afterClosed` event is documented (briefly) here: https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview

> The MatDialogRef provides a handle on the opened dialog. It can be
>   used to close the dialog and to receive notification when the dialog
>   has been closed.
>
> ```
> dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {   console.log(`Dialog
>    result: ${result}`); // Pizza! });
>
> dialogRef.close('Pizza!');
> ```

Comment: I tried both ways but error is coming `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'afterClosed' of undefined`