# How to reload/update a template of a component in Angular using MatDialogRef

Tags: angular, dialog, components, reload

I have a user management component (gestion-usuarios) that displays a list with all users. Within this component there is a button to add a new user. Clicking on this button opens a modal (a new component,nuevo-usuario-modal)with a form that fills it out and clicking on a save button that has the modal passes that new user to the user management component. It works but it doesn't dynamically update the user list with the new user. I use MatDialogRef.

how can I update the user list dynamically?  I want to reload only that component not the whole page.

**nuevo-usuario-modal.component.html**

```
<div class="modal-header">
  <h4 class="modal-title" id="modal-basic-title">{{title}}</h4>
  <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="cerrar()">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
  </button>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
  <form>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="dniCliente">DNI</label>
      <input id="dniCliente" class="form-control" name="dniCliente" [(ngModel)]="nuevoUsuario.dniCliente"> 
      <label for="nombre">Nombre</label>
      <input id="nombre" class="form-control" name="nombre" [(ngModel)]="nuevoUsuario.nombre">
      <label for="direccion">Direccion</label>
      <input id="direccion" class="form-control" name="direccion" [(ngModel)]="nuevoUsuario.direccion">
      <label for="email">Email</label>
      <input id="email" class="form-control" name="email" [(ngModel)]="nuevoUsuario.email">
      <label for="pwd">Contraseña</label>
      <input id="pwd" class="form-control" name="pwd" [(ngModel)]="nuevoUsuario.pwd">
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" [mat-dialog-close]="nuevoUsuario" (click)="guardarUsuario()">Guardar</button>
</div>
```

---

**nuevo-usuario-modal.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Output, EventEmitter,OnInit, ChangeDetectorRef, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialogRef,MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { IUsuario } from 'interfaces/iusuario';
import { UsuariosService } from '../usuarios.service';
import { DataService } from '../data.service';



@Component({
  selector: 'nuevo-usuario-modal',
  templateUrl: './nuevo-usuario-modal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./nuevo-usuario-modal.component.css']
})
export class NuevoUsuarioModalComponent implements OnInit {
  closeResult = '';
  title = "Nuevo cliente"

  usuarios: IUsuario[] = [];

  nuevoUsuario: IUsuario = {
    direccion: "",
    dniCliente: "",
    email: "",
    nombre: "",
    pwd: "",
  };


  constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<NuevoUsuarioModalComponent>,@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data,
   public ServicioUsuarios: UsuariosService,
    private dataService: DataService){}

  @Output() recargar = new EventEmitter();


  guardarUsuario() {

    this.ServicioUsuarios.crearUsuario(this.nuevoUsuario).subscribe(() => {
      this.dataService.usuarios.push(this.nuevoUsuario);
      console.log(this.dataService.usuarios);
    });

  }

  cerrar() {
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }

  ngOnInit() {}


}
```

**gestion-usuarios.component.html**

```
<div>
<p class="p-2">Gestión de usuarios <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="abrirModalNuevoUsuario()">Nuevo usuario</button></p>
<div>
    <form class="form">
        <div class="col-sm-5">
        <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="filtro" class="form-control"
        name="filtroNombre" id="filtroNombre" placeholder="Filtrando por...">
        </div>
        </form>
</div>

<div *ngFor="let usuario of usuarios | nombreUsuarioFiltro:filtro" class="p-2 divUsuariosIndividual">
    <div class="p-2 m-2">{{usuario.dniCliente}}</div>
    <div class="p-2 m-2">{{usuario.nombre}}</div>
    <div class="p-2 m-2">{{usuario.direccion}}</div>
    <div class="p-2 m-2">{{usuario.email}}</div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click) = "editar(usuario)">Editar</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" (click) = "borrar(usuario.dniCliente)" >Borrar</button>

</div>
```

**gestion-usuarios.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Output,EventEmitter, OnChanges, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
import { UsuariosService } from '../usuarios.service';
import { IUsuario } from '../../../interfaces/iusuario';
import { MatDialog, MatDialogConfig } from '@angular/material/dialog';


import { NuevoUsuarioModalComponent } from '../nuevo-usuario-modal/nuevo-usuario-modal.component'
import { EditarUsuarioModalComponent } from '../editar-usuario-modal/editar-usuario-modal.component';
import { DataService } from '../data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'gestion-usuarios',
  templateUrl: './gestion-usuarios.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./gestion-usuarios.component.css']
})
export class GestionUsuariosComponent implements OnInit,OnChanges {

  filtro: string = '';
   u: IUsuario = {
    direccion: "",
    dniCliente: "",
    email: "",
    nombre: "",
    pwd: "",
  }

  constructor(
    public ServicioUsuarios: UsuariosService,
    private dialog: MatDialog,public dataServicio: DataService


  ) { }

  borrar(dniCliente): void {
    var confirmacion = confirm("¿Seguro que quieres eliminar el usuario?");
    if (confirmacion) {
       this.ServicioUsuarios.borrarCliente(dniCliente).subscribe(() => this.ServicioUsuarios.getUsuariosArray().subscribe(
        recibe => this.usuarios = recibe,
        error => console.log(error),
      ));
    }
  }

  abrirModalNuevoUsuario() {

    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(NuevoUsuarioModalComponent);

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
    console.log(result);    
     this.usuarios.push(result);
     console.log(this.usuarios);

    })

  }

  editar(usuario) {
    this.dialog.open(EditarUsuarioModalComponent,{data: usuario});
  }

  usuarios: IUsuario[] = [];

  ngOnInit() {

    this.usuarios = this.dataServicio.getUsuarios();
    this.ServicioUsuarios.getUsuariosConsola();

    this.ServicioUsuarios.getUsuariosArray().subscribe(
      recibe => {
        this.usuarios = this.dataServicio.getUsuarios();

        this.usuarios = recibe;
      },
      error => console.log(error),
    );

  }

 ngOnChanges(){
   this.ngOnInit();
 }


}
```

**data.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { IUsuario } from 'interfaces/iusuario';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {

  usuarios: IUsuario[] = [];

  getUsuarios() {
    return this.usuarios;
  }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this file: nuevo-usuario-modal.component.ts

Change:

```
guardarUsuario() {

  this.ServicioUsuarios.crearUsuario(this.nuevoUsuario).subscribe(() => {
    this.dataService.usuarios.push(this.nuevoUsuario);
    console.log(this.dataService.usuarios);
  });

}
```

to

```
guardarUsuario() {

  this.ServicioUsuarios.crearUsuario(this.nuevoUsuario).subscribe(nuevoUsuar => {
    this.dialogRef.close(nuevoUsuar);
  });

}
```

I'm assuming crearUsuario is an endpoint which should return the user after it has been inserted into the database. Pass the user provided by the response back to the dialogRef you're subscribing to.

Comment: I have this.usuarios with the new user this.nuevoUsuario. But my problem is that I have this.usuarios with the new object in gestion-usuarios-component and the view/templete not update this new user

Comment: No, you do not have the new user in gestion-usuarios-component as you think you do. You never passed it back in the dialogRef.close method. Consider that a data service is also redundant here.

Comment: I don't undenstand how and where to write "this.dialogRef.close(this.nuevoUsuario);" Can you edit your answer please? I have to solve this urgently

Comment: I have change it. But it don't work. Cerrar method is only a span with a "x" to close the modal. In gestion-usuarios-modal in the abrirModalNuevoUsuario method I do a console.log of result (new user) and it is there. For this reason I think that I have the new data

Comment: It can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48723439/dynamically-load-a-component-inside-a-material-matdialog and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54107947/how-to-refresh-component-after-matdialog-close-and-data-updated-in-database-in-a I use afertClosed method to get the new user (it is result).

Comment: It is the official example https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview Please I need to solve it

Comment: Do not call ngOnInit within an ngOnChanges method. Remove ngOnChanges() completely.